# PHP Redirect Not Working on Script Containing SQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, submit, refresh

Alright so I've been pouring over this code for 16+ hours and I cannot find where the issue is. Before you say anything- I know I'm prone to SQL injection and I need to setup more prepared statements; once I get the code working my next step is to work on those issues. I also know I need to add the TRUE and 303 parameter to the Header call- I'm just trying to get it running at this point.

The code worked beautifully until I began working on eliminating form submission on refresh and adding redirects at the end.

The page that is having the problem is called updateorder.php and here is a Pastie link for it: http://pastie.org/9188291

I created a page called Issue.php to funnel everyone off the page and to eliminate the possibility of any of the html code outputting. That did not help.
I removed the ?> PHP closing tag from the end since all the code is PHP and eliminate any white space possibility. That didn't help either.

The page before this has several submit buttons. This page looks at what button was pushed and runs the code when it meets the conditions of the IF.

- When I submit the form using the DeleteThisOrder button, it operates perfectly.
- When I submit the form using the PrintOnly button, it operates perfectly.
- When I submit the form using the UpdateOnly button, but $ThisStatus <>1, it runs perfectly.

Here are the problems:

If I hit the UpdateOnly button and $ThisStatus does ==1, then it remains on this page (updateorder.php) and the screen is blank. 
The exact thing happens if I use the UpdateCommit button.

Something is happening when it runs this particular section of the UpdateOnly script: Sorry I don't have 10 reputation so it will not let me provide more links. Here is the Pastie number you can replace in the above Pastie link to see the code for this section: 9188298

And something happens when running this particular section of the UpdateCommit script: Sorry I don't have 10 reputation so it will not let me provide more links. Here is the Pastie number you can replace in the above Pastie link to see the code for this section: 9188306

Whatever it is doing it is causing it not to redirect. The SQL code executes and does everything it is supposed to do in the database; it's updating the order, it's updating inventory- all of that executes fine- it's just not redirecting and it stalls somewhere in the script before it redirects and leaves me with a blank screen.

I've done the advanced search on the site and looked at every thing I could find using the keywords PHP, MySQL, Redirect, with no clue as to why it's not working. I've went over this code line by line to look for white space, tried using the whole website address for the redirect, added a space between the colon and the link in the header... I've tried a lot of things. I've even tried unhealthy things like banging my head on my desk, hitting my head with my palm, and pulling my hair... no results. I really appreciate your time.

Just in case- here is the code in my required db connection file: Sorry I don't have 10 reputation so it will not let me provide more links. Here is the Pastie number you can replace in the above Pastie link to see the code for this section: 9188351

By the way... as you can probably tell I'm still learning so it may not be 'beautiful code' yet but I'm working on getting there. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: white page of death, error reporting\display are off, turn them on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: wow long story! Check your web server log to see if you can find some errors there.

Comment: makk those the first two lines of your file (after `<?php`)

Comment: Just put those 2 lines @Dragon posted in the beginning of the php block. better put it before `session_start();`

Comment: Try `if ($ThisStatus != 1) {` instead of `if ($ThisStatus <> 1) {` see if that makes it kick in.

Comment: @Dagon Alright this is making some headway. Alright so I added the two lines and used the submit button for UpdateOnly. It returned: Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object in /home/mydatabase/myrootfolder/updateorder.php on line 93. So I removed: $result->free(); and then did it again and it ran perfectly! I then used the UpdateCommit submit button and it returned the following errors: Notice: Undefined index: UpdateOnly in /home/mydatabase/myrootfolder/UpdateOrder.php on line 13
and ...

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object in /home/mydatabase/myrootfolder/UpdateOrder.php on line 135. I removed the $result->free(); and ran it again but it came up with these two errors: Notice: Undefined index: UpdateOnly in /home/mydatabase/myrootfolder/UpdateOrder.php on line 13
and...
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mydatabase/myrootfolder/UpdateOrder.php:13) in /home/mydatabase/myrootfolder/UpdateOrder.php on line 138

Comment: To get rid of that `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent` message, place `<?php session_start(); ?><?php // rest of your code...` as your first lines of code while getting rid of the other one where it's at now, followed by the rest of your code. Make sure there is nothing above that, HTML etc. including any white spaces. If you still get that error message, make sure it's saved as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: For the `Notice: Undefined index: UpdateOnly` make sure your form element is named with no typos. I.e. `name="UpdateOnly"` --- `UpdateOnly` is not the same as `updateonly`

Comment: Alright so in summary I had to remove $result->free(); from the two sections called UpdateOnly and UpdateCommit. I've always set a result free if I have run an SQL query; any idea why those two caused the issue but the other ones later in the script did not? Those two lines to display errors were perfect- are there any other lines of code I should know of for other types of errors? Also I'm not seeing an option to accept an answer or a button to upvote you guys... do I not have enough reputation? I wish I could tell you both thanks but the FAQ tells me not to...

Comment: Personally, I don't know why `$result->free();` would cause that (*unless you have a function called `free()` since I doubt it's a core function*), so I can't put in an answer for it. A formal answer isn't required. We're just glad it worked out for you. I'm no point monger myself ;-) Anyone else is more than welcome to do so.

Comment: Just leaving this for additional info in case someone reads this later and wonders; I **DON'T** have a function called free(). Strange...

Comment: Then that's the reason then. OK, I'll just put my comments to an answer and you can accept it once SO lets you. Give me a minute or so.

Comment: I've posted my answer for you below.

Comment: I don't know exactly what the `$result` object is, but if it is `mysql_result` or `mysqli_result` object then if there is now rows, or error it can return false, null so it would be better to check the object if it is valid before calling member functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in development add error reporting to the top of your file(s)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will signal any errors if they are found in your code.

As per the error message from your comments:

To get rid of that `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent...` message, place

`<?php session_start(); ?><?php // rest of your code...` as your first lines of code while getting rid of the other one where it's at now, followed by the rest of your code. Make sure there is nothing above that, HTML etc. including any white spaces. If you still get that error message, make sure it's saved as UTF-8 without BOM. (*Consult footnotes*)

For the `Notice: Undefined index: UpdateOnly` error message, make sure your form element is named with no typos. I.e. `name="UpdateOnly"` --- `UpdateOnly` is not the same as `updateonly` PHP is case-sensitive.

As for your `$result->free();` you mention you don't have that function, so just remove it.

---

**Footnotes:**

- BOM (aka byte order mark)

For more information on this subject, visit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

For more information on error reporting, visit: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I only had to put `<?php session_start(); //and then remainder of code` and it functions. I didn't have to close the PHP tag and reopen... but maybe that is a standard I'm not aware of. `$result` was just the result set from my SQL query execution as in `$result = $db->query($sql);` The error reporting lines was what led to the solution.

Comment: That's great. I'm always glad to hear that. @StatikStasis